# Estimations for the size of the biggest entry in an inverse Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If you got a Matrix $A$. Is there a estimation how big the largest element in the inverse of the matrix is?

If it helps the matrix is unimodular, that means all entries are integer and the determinant is +-1. The inverse is also unimodular.

Answer (score 4):

Just for illustration how bad it can be: consider an $n\times n$ lower triangular matrix $A$ with $1$ on the diagonal and $-1$ in the strictly lower triangular part. The matrix is clearly unimodular. However, the entry $(n,1)$ of $A^{-1}$ is equal to $2^{n-2}$ (so it grows very fast with $n$ even though $A$ is full of quite "innocent" numbers).

Comment: +1. Excellent example! It seems to be related to the power series   $\frac{1- 2 \mathfrak{n}}{1- \mathfrak{n}}$ in $\mathfrak{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is unimodular ( the determinant is $1$) then the inverse is the adjunct matrix $\text{adj} A$ ( in general it's $\frac{1}{\det A} \cdot \text{adj} A$). The matrix $\text{adj} A$ has as $(i,j)$ entry the algebraic complement of $a_{ij}$ in the expansion of the determinant $\det A$, that is, it's $(-1)^{i+j} M_{ji}$ where the minor $M_{ji}$ ( note the flipping of $i$, $j$ ) is the $n-1\times n-1 $ determinant obtained from $\det A$ by eliminating the row $j$ and column $i$. An estimate for $M_{ji}$ is given by the [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality). It is not clear to me right now that you cannot give a finer estimate that takes into account that the determinant of $A$ is $1$. This appears to be an interesting problem.

$\bf{Added}$ It seems that this exponent $n-1$ cannot be avoided, there is no linear estimate. For take a diagonal unimodular matrix, with diagonal $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$. Then $\frac{1}{\lambda_i} = \prod_{j \ne i} \lambda_j$. One could use the singular value decomposition and reach a similar estimate.

Comment: If you got a 1000x1000 matrix with max absolute value of 1000 then this inequality gives: $1000^{1000}*1000^{500}$ can it be really that large?

Comment: It's of the order of $M^{n-1}$ where $M$ is an upper bound for the absolute value of the entries of $A$. Think of a diagonal matrix with $999$ entries equal to $1000$ and the last one $1000^{-999}$. So the upper bound is of the order of $1000^{999}$. Thanks to the singular value decomposition, the estimate for diagonal unimodular matrices is about as good as the estimate for general unimodular matrices ( some factors of $n$ still appearing).

Comment: yes but your example is no unimodular matrix?

Comment: @orangeskid This is usually called the *adjugate*, not the adjoint. The term "adjoint" is used to refer to the adjoint with respect to an inner product. For the real Euclidean inner product this is the transpose, for the complex Euclidean inner product it is the conjugate transpose.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I should at least make an effort to distinguish it from the other adjoints. Would adjunct work? I just took a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: @testy: The diagonal matrix with $999$ diagonal entries equal to $1000$ and the last one to make the det $1$-- isn't that unimodular?

Comment: @Ian: Funny thing,  $\text{adj}A$ is nevertheless an adjoint- of the map  $\wedge^{n-1} A$. But I totally agree that it should not be called the adjoint of $A$. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: In an unimodular matrix all entries are integer.

Comment: @testy: Ah, gotcha. Definitely a more delicate thing. I will think about it. Perhaps you should make this explicit in the question, you will get more pertinent answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the max norm is dependent only on the largest element, you can use perturbation theorem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Choose $\bf v,u$ to be vectors, with one $\epsilon$ each and rest 0.

Numerator   : $\epsilon^2 {A^{-1}_{:,j} A^{-1}_{i,:}}$
Denominator : $1 - \epsilon^2 A_{ij}^{-1}$

For any (i,j) we can design $\epsilon$ so that $\epsilon^2A_{ij}^{-1}$ is arbitrary close to $1$. Then $\epsilon^2$ will be arbitrarily close to $\frac{1}{A_{ij}^{-1}}$. But $A_{ij}^{-1}$ occurs as a square in the numerator, so one factor will survive at position (i,j), while the denominator is arbitrarily close to 0.

Comment: what exactly does this tell me?

Comment: Let us assume that we know the index (i,j) for maximum element of $A^{-1}$. Then we can cause an arbitrary large change to it by adding a value to  $A_{i,j}$. 

It at least answers "can it really be that large?" you asked the other guy below.